# ExtJS refresh grid when object in store is changed

Tags: javascript, extjs, viewmodel

I have a store which contains an object, I have a viewmodel with this store and I have a grid with store bound to this viewmodel store.

Example: (In my case object in much more complex)

```js
const things = {car: 'Fiat', house: 'big'};

   Ext.define('MyApp.store.users', {
      extend  : 'Ext.data.Store',
      model   : 'MyApp.model.users',
      alias   : 'store.users',
      data    : [{
          name: 'john',
          things: things
      }]
   });

Ext.define('MyApp.model.users', {
   extend  : 'Ext.data.Model',
   alias   : 'model.users',
   fields: [{
      name : 'name'
   }, {
      name : 'things',
      type : 'boolean',
      calculate(d) { return isHouseBig(d.house) }
   }],
   proxy: {
      type : 'localstorage',
      id   : 'usb-devices'
   }
});

things.car = 'Ferrari';
```

So, how can I get my grid to update when I change for example the value of `house`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ExtJS refreshes the grid automatically when the store is changed. The problem here that you have use `mapping` in the model definition when you data comes as a JSON object, [check documentation here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.4.0/classic/Ext.data.field.Field.html#cfg-mapping). When you set up your fields like this, if you modify store data, the grid will reflect changes automatically.

Check the following code, at the end comment out the two lines to see the difference when these are executed. You can find this simplified example [here as a working fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3fes).

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.users', {
   extend  : 'Ext.data.Model',
   fields: [{
      name : 'name'
   },{
      name : 'things',
   },{
      name : 'car',
      // so in every model `car` will represent `things.car`
      mapping : 'things.car',
   },{
      name : 'house',
      mapping : 'things.house',
   }],
});

Ext.define('MyApp.store.users', {
    extend  : 'Ext.data.Store',
    model   : 'MyApp.model.users',
    data    : [{
      name: 'john',
      things: {car: 'Fiat', house: 'big'}
    },{
      name: 'mary',
      things: {car: 'Opel', house: 'small'}
    }],
    proxy: {
      type: 'memory'
    }
});

const usersStore = Ext.create('MyApp.store.users');

const usersGrid = Ext.create({
    xtype: 'grid',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    store: usersStore,
    width: 400,
    height: 200,
    title: 'Users',
    columns: [{
        text: 'name',
        dataIndex: 'name'
    },{
        text: 'car',
        dataIndex: 'car'
    },{
        text: 'house',
        dataIndex: 'house'
    }]
});

// uncomment these lines to see change

//usersStore.getAt(1).set('car', 'newCar');
//usersStore.getAt(1).set('house', 'newHouse');
```

Comment: Sorry, my questions wasn't very clear. The problem is that if I update the object somewhere else it doesn't update the grid. Please see your forked fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3ff7

Comment: Ok, I understand. That will not work with ExtJS. Constants `things1` and `things2` will be used by the proxy when store is created, but the store will not contain reference to these constants, these are separate variables.

Comment: Store is a collection of models, and models contain a lot of internal data added by ExtJS, and model field values in your case are copied from the constants when populating the store, but live an independent life afterwards.

Comment: Add a breakpoint to your fiddle before `things1.car = 'Ferrari` and check local variables in the watch, under `usersStore.data.items` you will see the array of your models, and you can see the difference.

Comment: And this works: `usersStore.data.items[0].data.car = 'Ferrari';
usersStore.data.items[0].data.house = 'Huge';`, but the highly recommended way is using ExtJS `set` and other functions, as in the answer.